# R: loop to subset, append data, and output single data frame

Tags: r, loops, append, subset

I have two separate data sets, `df1` and `df2`, (each with differing number of rows) that I need to match and then append columns with particular values from `df2`. I have a large data set and am getting stuck with writing a loop to match each row of `df2` to `df1` and then append desired values...

The data in `df1` is matched to `df2` based on dates. Each iteration returns a different number of rows based on how many records from `df1` match with `df2`. I then need to take the relevant columns with desired values from `df2` and append them to the output from date matching. Here is a manual example (which works and gives me what I need):

```
# Step 1: Get the desired values from df2 that need to be appended to the matching output
  df2_values = df2[, c("trip.start", "trip.end", "b","ln_b,"c","ln_c")] 

# Step 2: Find the df1 records inclusive of the dates for the first record in df2
  df1_rec = subset(df1, Date >= df2$trip.start[1] & Date <= df2$trip.end[1])

# Step 3: Append the date matching output and the df2 values
  output1 = cbind(df1_rec, df2_values[1,])

# Doing this again for df2, second date
  df1_rec = subset(df1, Date >= df2$trip.start[2] & Date <= df2$trip.end[2]) 
  output2 = cbind(df1_rec, df2_values[2,])
```

I need to repeat this process for 40 rows of df2 and then rbind all outputs together, and then again for 737 individual occurrences. Here's what I've attempted so far, none of which have worked:

```
    # Attempt #1
       library(foreach)
       output = foreach (j=1:nrow(df2), .combine=rbind) %do% {
       cbind(subset(df1, Date >= df2$trip.start[j] & Date <= df2$trip.end[j]), df2_values[j,]) }

    Error in { : 
  task 7 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"

# Attempt #2
       for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
       df1_rec = subset(df1, Date >= df2$trip.start[j] & Date <= df2$trip.end[j])
       output = cbind(df1_rec, df2_values[j,]) }

    Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

# Attempt #3
   library(foreach)
   output = foreach(i=1:nrow(df2), .combine=rbind) %do% {
            for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {
            df1_rec = subset(df1, Date >= df2$trip.start[j] & Date <= df2$trip.end[j])
            df2_rec = df2_values[j,]
             cbind(df1_rec, df2_rec)} 
             }
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"
```

Here's my workable data:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Date = c("01-06-2008", "01-12-2008", "01-12-2008", 
"03-29-2008", "03-29-2008", "03-30-2008", "03-30-2008", "03-30-2008", 
"04-03-2008", "04-03-2008", "04-22-2008", "04-22-2008", "04-25-2008", 
"04-25-2008", "04-26-2008", "04-26-2008", "06-01-2010", "06-02-2010", 
"06-02-2010", "06-02-2010", "06-11-2010", "06-13-2010", "06-19-2010", 
"06-25-2010", "06-26-2010", "09-06-2010", "09-10-2010", "09-11-2010", 
"09-11-2010", "09-11-2010"), LONGITUDE = c(-83.93867, -84.11667, 
-84.158, -83.89933, -83.90333, -84.03533, -84.038, -84.01267, 
-84.14267, -84.18933, -84.01267, -84.02733, -83.49867, -83.98133, 
-84.194, -84.148, -83.99933, -83.75733, -83.76333, -83.802, -83.79333, 
-83.836, -83.78733, -83.92333, -84.23267, -83.79867, -84.15, 
-84.07533, -84.082, -84.10333), LATITUDE = c(29.38467, 29.262, 
29.19333, 28.89467, 28.866, 29.05933, 29.1, 29.074, 29.056, 29.01267, 
29.52467, 29.488, 29.62267, 29.05867, 29.17067, 29.208, 29.29933, 
29.08333, 29.05, 29.05267, 29.114, 29.09933, 29.18533, 29.04333, 
28.83533, 29.16133, 29.256, 29.254, 29.30867, 29.32667)), .Names = c("Date", 
"LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"), row.names = c(1L, 20L, 21L, 211L, 212L, 
213L, 214L, 215L, 249L, 250L, 339L, 340L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 370L, 
72196L, 72197L, 72198L, 72199L, 72229L, 72237L, 72261L, 72302L, 
72303L, 72456L, 72493L, 72494L, 72495L, 72496L), class = "data.frame")


> dput(df2)
structure(list(trip.start = c("01-06-2008", "01-12-2008", "03-29-2008", 
"04-03-2008", "04-21-2008", "04-25-2008", "05-30-2008", "06-12-2008", 
"06-27-2008", "12-19-2008", "12-20-2008", "12-28-2008", "01-02-2009", 
"05-08-2009", "05-30-2009", "06-05-2009", "06-11-2009", "06-14-2009", 
"06-19-2009", "07-11-2009"), trip.end = c("01-06-2008", "01-12-2008", 
"03-30-2008", "04-04-2008", "04-22-2008", "04-26-2008", "05-31-2008", 
"06-13-2008", "06-28-2008", "12-19-2008", "12-20-2008", "12-28-2008", 
"01-03-2009", "05-09-2009", "05-30-2009", "06-06-2009", "06-12-2009", 
"06-16-2009", "06-20-2009", "07-11-2009"), b = c(29, 80.2, 50.3589743589744, 
34.6666666666667, 46.4117647058824, 44.0555555555556, 28.6511627906977, 
34.7179487179487, 35.4871794871795, 37.3846153846154, 34.5555555555556, 
103.764705882353, 25.6875, 25.9333333333333, 34, 40.3529411764706, 
28.3448275862069, 25.1764705882353, 30.6896551724138, 47.3333333333333
), ln_b = c(3.36729582998647, 4.38452351487247, 3.91917684278476, 
3.54577861047326, 3.83755297678966, 3.78545146373868, 3.3551940283999, 
3.54725680734257, 3.56917149004797, 3.62125926643896, 3.54256833484301, 
4.64212589251052, 3.24600449225645, 3.25552914251624, 3.52636052461616, 
3.69766428366967, 3.34444456506971, 3.22590985152558, 3.42392563273971, 
3.85721476893315), c = c(680.8023262, 2656.955794, 7593.859146, 
4124.485734, 5422.506164, 5251.09887, 3739.569761, 3577.070057, 
3572.918367, 1604.339982, 2090.724546, 5934.445367, 2302.743139, 
2574.448603, 1095.623765, 3377.839478, 2109.856165, 3065.508244, 
2118.826924, 1424.613609), ln_c = c(6.52327199411584, 7.88493630806025, 
8.93509519255547, 8.32469662045131, 8.59831337944543, 8.56619264225512, 
8.22672584662552, 8.18229932447399, 8.18113801057517, 7.38046772481922, 
7.64526595760902, 8.68852885145536, 7.74185636038285, 7.85339065541043, 
6.99907912846437, 8.12499157640442, 7.65437505590011, 8.02796865648309, 
7.65861787678239, 7.26165590435557)), .Names = c("trip.start", 
"trip.end", "b", "ln_b", "c", "ln_c"), row.names = c(16699L, 
16724L, 17055L, 17081L, 17162L, 17187L, 17383L, 17461L, 17558L, 
18176L, 18191L, 18223L, 18255L, 18732L, 18832L, 18888L, 18941L, 
18979L, 19015L, 19124L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [`apply`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/):

```
# Go through each row of df2 and do the matching.
# Return the `cbind`-ed df if matches found.
# The '1' in `apply(df2, 1, ...) means 'do-by-row'.
df12 <- apply(df2, 1, function(df2Row){
    matches <- df1$Date >= df2Row["trip.start"] & df1$Date <= df2Row["trip.end"];
    if(sum(matches) > 0){
        # Had to transpose df2Row before doing data.frame(..).
        # or it would make a single column df with 6 rows instead!
        # Very weird...
        cbind(df1[matches, ], data.frame(t(df2Row)));
    } else {
        NULL;
    }
})

# Now bind all the dfs in the list output above into 
# a single data.frame
df12 <- do.call(rbind, df12);
```

There are better ways to do this that use the [`dplyr` library](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) (well worth learning!), but if you want to stick to base `R`, then the above is one way you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I was also able to use it rather easily in a loop (using the 'foreach' function) for all 737 combinations of df1 and df2.

Comment: Great! If that answered your question, then go ahead and accept the answer :)